# MikTeX Update and LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex

Since the Miktex Update yesterday LuaTeX doesn't work any longer.
Running from command line, I only get the following output:

```
>lualatex Main.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 4971)
```

and nothing thereafter. Anyone got the same problem or an idea how to solve it?
FNDB and Formats are updated.

Comment: What does the file `Main.tex` contain? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: At first search for updates again. There has been some problems with the update yesterday.

Comment: @Mico It doesn't even reach to `Main.tex`, this is a genuine MikTeX problem I'm afraid.

Comment: I have the same problem, even with the 32bit version. No error message ist given. The problem occurs whe you update "miktex-luatex-bin-2.9" from "09-Jul-13" to "21-Mar-15".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not find more updates. It indeed seems to be a genuine Miktex problem.

Comment: I got today an update of miktex-runtime-bin-2.9 and the oberdiek package, which repaired two issues I reported yesterday. This updates are also anounced on the web page. If you didn't got them, check with other repositories. Also run the update manager in admin+user mode. And recreate the formats in user mode. Lualatex works fine for me (I have miktex 32bit).

Comment: On another PC updated today I saw this problem too, but it was gone after I recreated the (user) format.

Comment: see my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235042/why-lualatex-could-crash/235044#235044, where Ulrike Fischer answers how to solve problem step by step.