# Why does Lualatex crash after a recent update?

Tags: errors, luatex, miktex

After updating packages of MiKTEX 2.9 `lualatex` stopped working.

I execute this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] at (0,0) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I get this error:

```
"Process started: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex Error: Command crashed: lualatex.exe -synctex=1
-interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex Process exited with error(s)"
```

Why does the command crash? What should be done to continue my work?

PDFLatex and XeLatex work fine, but I need lualatex, cause my thesis is with lualatex.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234628/miktex-update-and-luatex. There is a very recent bug in the latest build

Comment: Recreate the lualatex format (in doubt as user not with miktex settings (admin)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, what do you mean?

Comment: Open miktex settings, go to the tab format, select lualatex and click on build.

Comment: Please edit the question title to be more specific/informative.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you.  I never knew how to get MikTeX to compile using lualatex until you provided your comment.

Comment: @percusse: That question has no answers while this one has.

Comment: Note that there are other official MikTeX support forums; see [here](http://www.miktex.org/help). This might warrant a bug report.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) comment (see above) "**Open `Miktex settings`, go to the tab `Formats`, select `lualatex` and click on `Build`**" First do it in `admin` mode, then in `user` mode.

Now everything is working!

[image]

Comment: You opened miktex settings (admin). As it worked this is fine. But if a user format exists then one should use the "non-admin" miktex settings to overwrite it.

Comment: Doing that fixed lualatex on my workstation, but I can't seem to be able to fix an install on Windows 2003 server. Logged in as the user which lualatex runs under, built the format, but still the same problem. And pdflatex no longer works there either. This is a catastrophe.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After the todays update, the update program itself crashes before fetching the available updates. How are you proposing to install further updates?

Comment: @ajeh: You can always get packages from CTAN and move them to a local repository and install from there (if mpm is still working). But I would at first try to run the manager from the command line. Btw: That pdflatex isn't working could mean that you have quite a different problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  After running settings repeatedly under the service user and logging on and off, I finally got pdflatex working. But lualatex works only under my own account (which is a domain admin) and not under the service account. What could that be? Do I need to blow away some files from the service account's home directory?

Comment: @ajeh: I have no idea what's going on on your machine. There is not enough informations. But you could try to remove lualatex.exe and lualatex.fmt  (you can find it with `kpsewhich --all --engine=luatex lualatex.fmt`) and then to recreate both by updating the format. And don't panic: there is always the alternative texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Was too optimistic, nothing works now. Can I go back to a 1 year ago MikTex, as this is a total show stopper and production is down???

Comment: @ajeh: If you have a backup -- certainly. But not with miktex tools. I don't think that you should continue to discuss this in comments to this question. lualatex works fine here, you have some special problem on your system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is it possible to include more detailed diagnostic messages in the MikTex programs? If lualatex is missing something, it should print an error message, not just quit silently.

Comment: @ajeh: I'm not the miktex maintainer. If you have bug report or a feature request: https://sourceforge.net/projects/miktex/.

Comment: I cannot do this in Miktex settings as an administrator (the list in formats is empty). When I do it as normal used and click "Build" an "error reading Lualatex.ini" happens.)

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me after building format files was not sufficient (`pdflatex` kept throwing errors re dump file not found and `lualatex` just quit silently):

1. Uninstall MikTex.
2. Blow away all instances of MikTex folders under all of the user's folders.
3. Reinstall MikTex (the most recent version).

In my special scenario there were additional steps required due to running `lualatex` from an ASP.NET web page under a service account using impersonation, but the first 3 at least allowed the regular users to compile.

Comment: The usual Windows voodo: Reinstall the software. :-(

Comment: After I spent almost entire day trying to restore business as usual after the accursed update killed everything, and the proposed solution worked only for the users who had the admin rights, the solution I posted worked for everyone. Think of that before you downvote and then think again before trying to justify downvoting.